# Primary key or foreign key for table with identical unique columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

See indicative schema below.

Table 2 contains the different formats of films. E.g. 2D, 3D, 4D etc.

It has the formats as the columns and the end column is the film ID number from table 1.

As my film ID column in table 1 is my primary key for table 1, It lead my to believe that the film ID column in table 2 is a foreign key. However this leaves my without a primary key in table 2.

Is it best practice to leave table 2 without a primary key in this instance, or set both film IDs as primary keys for both tables, or should I create another column in table 2 allowing for a "film format ID" which would be my table 2 primary key?

For visual reference:

```
table 1                   table 2                                           
-------|-------           -------|-------|-------|-------
Film   |film ID           Film ID|  3D   |  4D   |  2D
        ^primary key      ^foreign key
```

Comment: what is the reasoning of splitting these two tables? if the relationship between them is 1 to 1?.

Comment: Where are the 5d films stored?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that many films come in multiple formats, so it would be mistake to make filmid a PK in the second table. Further the design is not normalized and highly flawed. You should have a third table of Film types that is a look up table. Then the second table should contain only the filmid and the filmtypeid and you can create a Primary key on the combination of both fields. THis is called a junction table.

Comment: So there would be three tables, table1 would have the columns film:filmID then table 2 would be filmID:filmFormatID and table 3 would be 2D:3D:4D:filmFormatID where FormatID would be different in for every film, also would be the primary key in table 3, with table 2 both columns the primary key and table1 filmID would be the primary key? This would then mean the database is normalised for 1NF right?

Comment: Table three would be formatId, format type. You do not ever want to have columns 2d, 3d, 4d.  The records in it would be 2D, 3D, 4D not the columns

Answer (score 0):

Table 2 is like a child to your table 1, been the parent. This is because table 1 can exist without table 2, but table 2 cannot without table 1 because it relies on the film id primary key to create itself a set of information (you cant have a 2d or 3d formats of a non existent film).

To answer your question about making film id primary in both tables; no don't do this. The primary key uniquely identifies a column of data in a table that can be referenced with a foreign key in another table. If it was also primary key in table 2 it wouldn't refer to table 1's data because there is no relationship made.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your needs, you can use those two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `film` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `film_format` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `film_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `format` enum('2D','3D','4D') CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT '2D',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk` (`film_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`film_id`) REFERENCES `film` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: I think you mean film not firm? This would work though I am not fond of enums because you then have to alter the table to add more. I prefer that there be a lookup table instead for Film Types.

Comment: ff.id is (presumably) redundant, as the remaining columns can form a composite natural key.

Comment: @HLGEM I share your concern, but they *are* efficient, and new formats probably don't come along all that often.

Comment: @HLGEM Firm was fixed, Thanks.. About the lookup table it depends how much formats exist, if it few options i suggest you to use a Enum and you will save many joins to lookup table. It's known dilemma! :)

Comment: @Strawberry it's recommended to set row identifier each table.

Answer (score 0):

You are having trouble because your table design violates [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).  Each unique combination of [film,format] should be contained in its own row in table 2.

May I suggest this alternative:

**Table 1**

A list of films, with a primary key of FilmID.

**Table 2**

A list of formats supported by films.

Columns: FilmID (FK), FormatID (FK)

Primary key: Either a compound key of FilmID+FormatID, or a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)

**Table 3**

A list of potential film formats

Columns: FormatID, Format Description (2D, 3D, etc.)

Primary key: FormatID

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a primary key on table 2, just an unique index.
But if you want, you can use an artificial key like an identity field. In this instance, at 1x1 relationship, i think thas's unnecessary.

Comment: So I make it a foreign key and add a unique constraint to the film Id column to table two and that's best practise?

Comment: I think so. But keep in mind: you don't need 2 tables at this case. You have a 1x1 relationship, and i think that the best approach is join those tables. But, it's your decision.

Comment: All tables in an RDBMS should have  a PRIMARY KEY. The question is only whether that key should be a natural key, or a surrogate.

Comment: I did try to say 'it's no mandatory', and really it is not. Relationship will be established over film_id field. However, i'd suggested an identity field to do it.